# Correlation between monthly and quarterly data

Tags: time-series, correlation, frequency, macroeconomics

Does anybody know how to measure the correlation between monthly and quarterly data?

I would like to calculate the correlation between ISM PMI (monthly) and Real GDP growth (quarterly).
So, the 2 time series have different frequencies, and different number of datapoints.

The correlation between PMI and US Real GDP Growth with a 12 month time lag, is supposedly around 85%. How can this be calculated?

If your answer should include an example, then preferably in R or Excel.

Source data can be viewed and downloaded here:
PMI : https://www.quandl.com/data/FRED/NAPM-ISM-Manufacturing-PMI-Composite-Index
GDP : https://www.quandl.com/data/FRED/A191RO1Q156NBEA-Real-Gross-Domestic-Product

Comment: down sample PMI by averaging or some other mean

Comment: You could just replicate each quarterly measurement in one series 3 times to compare with monthly data in the other. But if you correlate then two things are mixed up, the underlying correlation that you would have got if you had had monthly data not quarterly, and the effects of the coarsening to quarters (which might push the correlation either way, so far as I can see). There might be some scope for investigating the effects of the coarsening. But you aren't the first person to have this problem with economic time series, so there should be economic or econometric literature to consult.

Comment: To make this answerable, could you explain what such a correlation would *mean*? "Correlation" is a concept that applies, strictly speaking, to *paired* data, which these are not. It's conceivable that you are viewing one (or both) of these time series as being temporal aggregates of more refined time series, which themselves are not directly observed, and perhaps you are asking how to *estimate* some underlying correlation between those unobserved series? It may be worth noting that questions like this one are asked and answered in geostatistics: search "change of support."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go back to basics and ask, "What is a correlation?" The right answer is that there are many measures of "correlation" when broadly considered as pairwise metrics for demonstrating association between variables. The naive answer is that it's a *Pearson* correlation since that's the most commonly taught and known form. But Pearson correlations only measure pairwise, *linear* association and, moreover, have a rigorous requirement for interval or ratio scaled data. *Spearman* correlations, on the other hand, measure monotonic association, e.g., between ordinally scaled variables. For financial data which don't always meet the requirements of a Pearson, Spearman correlations are a much more sensible metric.

There are also many, many measures of association for categorically scaled data, as well as nonlinear measures of association such as "distance" correlations, and so on.

In addition, both Pearson and Spearman correlations range between $-1$ and $1$. Given that (and Street vernacular notwithstanding), it's completely erroneous to speak of them in percentage terms.

Not knowing where you got this rule of thumb of a 12 period lag resulting in an "85%" correlation between GDP and PMI, what is your goal? In other words, why are you even interested in replicating such a hoary convention? Moreover, you have such a long time series from Quandl -- back to 1950 -- what is it that makes you so concerned about the difference in the units of time?

What would I do to address your question? I would merge the two series with 3 monthly periods per quarter and do a whole lot of exploratory analytics: scatterplots, time lines, etc. Based on that, next I would run both Pearson *and* Spearman correlations using different lags, e.g., 1 quarter up to whatever you think a reasonable maximum # of lags is. Then, I would examine where the association was maximized. That's it.

Of course there are more rigorous ways to answer the question that go beyond simple measures of pairwise association, but that's not what you're asking for.

Comment: +1. Provocative as always, but the sharp distinction between Pearson as requiring interval scale and Spearman as suitable for ordinal scale is quite overdone, as Spearman correlation is nothing but Pearson correlation applied to ranks. So, you are condemning on the one hand what you encourage on the other. But that's one detail only.

Comment: @NickCox  But that difference in scaling is the point, not their calculation.

Comment: I don't see what extra point you are making there. My point is that Pearson correlation can be, and is, applied to ordinal, interval and ratio data; it's just conventional to call it Spearman when the data are ordinal. (The inference is in detail different.)

Comment: @NickCox  Of course it is applied to many scale types. This doesn't make it correct. I'll defer to Paul Embrechts on that. See his excellent paper on *Correlation and Dependency in Risk Management: Properties and Pitfalls* here: https://people.math.ethz.ch/~embrecht/ftp/pitfalls.pdf

Comment: On Spearman and Pearson, I don't see that you have addressed my point directly. But it's a matter of algebra **only** that pushing ranks through Pearson correlation gives the same result as Spearman correlation. The controversial question of what is appropriate for what scale type is alongside, but not at all the same, and I am not raising any of that here.  I made the same point in discussion of Hand, D.J. 1996. Statistics and the theory of measurement. _Journal of the Royal Statistical Society. Series A_ 159: 445–492 http://doi.org/10.2307/2983326 (see pp.481-2), but it's quite standard.

Comment: Thank you both for taking such a great interest in my question. I'm not a statistician, so I'm a bit lost here. I was hoping there would be a simple way to calculate the correlation, preferably with an example in R. I do have RStudio installed, but the possibilities to handle and analyze time series are seemingly endless. I've googled quite a bit, but cannot seem to find an answer or examples. The reason I'm trying to calculate it, is that someone told me there's a 85% correlation between both. I'd just like to verify that.

Comment: @DJohnson You say "I would merge the two series with 3 monthly periods per quarter". What do you mean by that? Convert the quarterly to monthly? Which values do you assign to the new datapoints then?

Comment: Bjorn: Although DJohnson has raised some very interesting issues, I suspect that almost everyone in your field would use Pearson correlation for your data, and I've commented above to that effect. Sorry, but I don't use R beyond very elementary level and can't offer code. But there will (surely) be a way to convert quarterly series to monthly series in R. For that question, use R help or Stack Overflow, but a reproducible example would help any such question.

Comment: Nick Cox is correct in noting that the Pearson is the standard metric of association in finance. For a different opinion about that, as well as its pitfalls, see the Embrechts' paper cited above. Embrechts is one of the most senior and respected scholars in financial risk management and his opinions should outweigh, by a long shot, a nonfinancial statistician's no matter how good. Regardless, rather than recommending a single metric, I would still look at it from the perspective of both. They can and frequently do give different answers in terms of the magnitude of the association.

Comment: Finally, interpolating monthly data up to quarterly is not only not necessary, in my opinion, it could blunt potentially useful variability in the monthly series. I wouldn't do it or, if you do, then at least look at it uninterpolated to see what and how the answer changes.

Comment: On the practical question, I don't know how you interpolate monthly data to quarterly or why it is supposed to be needed. The suggestion I made in a comment on the question is to expand the quarterly data to monthly, so for example a value of 42 for 2016 Q1 would become 42 42 42 for 2016 Jan Feb Mar. You could, I suppose, try smoothing the quarterly data, or something else; I don't recommend that.

Comment: @NickCox I just tried a quick correlation in Excel (Pearson I guess) with GDP expanded to monthly data.
Correlations are:
(a) PMI vs GDP (not time lagged): 0,651956425
(b) PMI (+12months) vs GDP : 0,122703334
(c) PMI vs GDP (-12 months) : -0,264587549
So, no 85% to be seen.

I was expecting (b) and (c) the have the same correlation.
A 12m shift forward in PMI or a 12m shift backward in GDP is essentially the same, no?
I don't understand why the correlations between (b) and (c) are different.

Comment: I think you now have a different question, probably for an economics forum.

Comment: Nick Cox and I agree about one thing and that's that it's appropriate to move this thread to a different forum, probably financial (not economic).

Comment: @nickcox This comment is not intended for the OP. It's a link to a Columbia U Statistics Dept conference two years ago on nonparametric measures of dependence. The presentations will probably be of interest to you... http://dependence2013.wikischolars.columbia.edu/Nonparametric+measures+of+dependence+workshop

Comment: Thanks for the reference. The "energy statistics" work is a thread I really need to follow up. In contrast, MIC seems vastly oversold to me from what I read. I've not programmed or worked with either.